# Are the properties assigned by the window.open command available to be used elsewhere?

Tags: javascript, google-forms

Essentially, what I'm trying to do is send users from another location to a survey. I'm attempting to avoid creating a survey for every single source location, since I need a unique survey for each one. However, all I have to do is autofill the first short answer question with the title of the previous location.

My understanding of the window.open command is that you can define the URL, the window name, and features following the command. Does the window name persist after the window is opened, or is it only accessible in the location in which it is defined (i.e. the code in the source location)? If it does, I'm fairly confident I could simply return the windowName into a variable in a script for the google form, then input that variable into the short answer.

Thoughts? Is this possible, or am I crazy?

Comment: You might want to check out [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name).

Comment: @IsaacStewart I'm not understanding..can u explain in any other way?

Comment: @SajjanSarkar Sure!
Under the window.open command, I can indicate the URL I want to use, the name, and any other special characteristics I want to apply to the new window. http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml

What I'm wondering is if I can set a window name in an application that I'm using to open a URL (specifically, a google form), then pull down that name into a script for the google form. This will enable me to create only one form for multiple sets of sources, instead of creating a unique form for every source I create.
Does that make sense?

Comment: @MikeC Interesting. Is is possible to set the window name in an application, as opposed to setting it in the website itself? I need the application that sends the user to the URL to define a unique name somewhere in the information that's sent, and it doesn't seem that I can do so with window.name.

Comment: @IsaacStewart I'd have to try it and find out. Or you can do what they suggest on that link and use `postMessage` to send information to the other window.